# Can't find rqpd package

Tags: r

I can't download the rqpd package; I can't find it in the list of packages.
Could you please help me?

I tried `install.packages('rqpd')` code and tried as well to look for it in the list of packages and did not find it.

Comment: You need to install from `install.packages("rqpd", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` as mentioned [here](https://rqpd.r-forge.r-project.org/)

Comment: Yes, I did so and it worked successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried the following command

```
install.packages("rqpd", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

and seems to work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/rqpd_0.6.tar.gz

You can download the package file to your working and install it.